# Certificate chain returning NULL after tomcat upgrade

Tags: java, tomcat, certificate

Following line of code was running fine when the deployment serve was Tomcat 6.0 with JDK 1.6.

```
 Object certChain = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

But when I upgraded tomcat server to 7.0 with JDK 1.7, above line of code is returning NULL certificate chain.

Is there any change in configuration which is causing this? or way of getting certificate chain now has been changed?

Any suggestions are welcome. Please help its urgent. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are having custom SSLImplemention for tomcat connector. There are few changes in JRE 1.7 which was causing the issue. The code was not receiving certificate on SSL communication.